# PHP Session Function Debug Assist

Tags: php, function, session

I know how to include external PHP pages and how to start sessions etc, but I think there is something messed up with my logic on what I am working on. Hoping someone could take a look...

I have an html page that is a form that pulls up a PHP view page with the info it sends to it. I wanted to put my function in an external page, along with using sessions, but I keep getting a syntax error.

When I send my form it goes to the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'functs.php'; 
if ($_POST && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['time'] = $_POST['time'];
confirmed();
}
else {
print unconfirmed();
}
?>
```

My external page with the functions is this:

```
<?php
function confirmed() {
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>Confirmation Page</title>";
echo '</head>";
echo "<body>";

PRINT <<<HERE

if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
echo 'Thank you, '.$_SESSION['name']. ' your reservation is confirmed for ' . $_SESSION['time'] ;
}
else {
echo 'There seems to have been an error processing your reservation. Please ensure that  you have cookies enabled and try your request again' ;
}

HERE;

echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

The error I am getting is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\cis\w2\functs.php on line 10. If I insert the function internally, it works, so I know its something with how I am formatting the include page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty obvious via the syntax highlighting what is wrong here:

```
echo '</head>";
//-----------^
```

This line has the incorrect quote mark, thus you never terminate the string, and it keeps going.

**Edit**:

But that isn't the only problem.  You also never close your function with a right curly bracket: `}`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have mismatched quotes on this line:

```
echo '</head>";
```

However, I have to say I'm confused as to why you have the HEREDOC. Surely you just need the `if` statement alone?

Comment: I never used to be a fan of IDEs with color-coding, but they're great for catching errors like this.

Comment: Thank you both!! In regards to the HEREDOC, I had that in there because I am just learning PHP and am playing around with different formats and getting used to different commands. I was so focused on thelogic, I didnt even look at the quotes in the code. Yikes.